# read form data from iframe

Tags: jquery, html, forms, iframe

how do I read form data that a user inputed from an iframe?

without the iframe, i would do something like this:

The jQuery:

```
function getRowData(id, parent){
    var data = [];
    $(parent+' table tr').each(function(){
        var row = {};
        $(this).find('select, input, textarea').each(function(){
            if(($(this).attr('id') == id) && (typeof $(this).attr('name') !== 'undefined' && $(this).attr('name') !== false)){
                row['id'] = id;
                row[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();

            }
        });
        data.push(row);
    });
    return data;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<table id="form-table">
<td><input type="checkbox" name="n_available" checked="checked"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="n_oem" checked="checked"></td>
</table>
```

and call the jQuery :

```
$('.get-data').live('click', function () {
    postData = $(this).attr("id");

    getRowData("form-table", $(this).attr("id");//here i have my form in an array...

});
```

now, if the html is in an iframe, how do i get the data?

Comment: Is the `iframe`s page coming from the same domain?

Comment: yes it is coming from the same domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `iframe`'s inner document and elements using this syntax:

```
$("#your_iframe_id").contents().find("body"); //this returns the body of the iframe
$("#your_iframe_id").contents().find("#form-table"); //this returns the table form-container inside the iframe
```

I hope that helped!